# Angular Form is not setting up FormControl for just the first field in in my form

Tags: html, angular, typescript, forms, angular-reactive-forms

I have been struggling with this issue for a few weeks now and can not figure out what is causing it. **(Angular version: 16.1.4)**

I am populating this form component with a BehaviorSubject, and when printing to console, the form and database are returning all the correct values, however, the form throws the following error for whatever field comes first in the html template.

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'empNum'
    at _throwError (forms.mjs:3150:11)
    at setUpControl (forms.mjs:2933:13)
    at FormGroupDirective.addControl (forms.mjs:4782:9)
    at FormControlName._setUpControl (forms.mjs:5370:43)
    at FormControlName.ngOnChanges (forms.mjs:5315:18)
    at FormControlName.rememberChangeHistoryAndInvokeOnChangesHook (core.mjs:2849:14)
    at callHookInternal (core.mjs:3841:14)
    at callHook (core.mjs:3872:9)
    at callHooks (core.mjs:3823:17)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.mjs:3773:9)
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'invalid')
    at HistoryFormComponent_Template (history-form.component.ts:19:15)
    at ReactiveLViewConsumer.runInContext (core.mjs:10414:13)
    at executeTemplate (core.mjs:10954:22)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:12475:13)
    at detectChangesInView (core.mjs:12639:9)
    at detectChangesInComponent (core.mjs:12615:5)
    at detectChangesInChildComponents (core.mjs:12653:9)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:12525:13)
    at detectChangesInView (core.mjs:12639:9)
    at detectChangesInComponent (core.mjs:12615:5)
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'invalid')
    at HistoryFormComponent_Template (history-form.component.ts:19:15)
    at ReactiveLViewConsumer.runInContext (core.mjs:10414:13)
    at executeTemplate (core.mjs:10954:22)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:12475:13)
    at detectChangesInView (core.mjs:12639:9)
    at detectChangesInComponent (core.mjs:12615:5)
    at detectChangesInChildComponents (core.mjs:12653:9)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:12525:13)
    at detectChangesInView (core.mjs:12639:9)
    at detectChangesInComponent (core.mjs:12615:5)
```

I can switch around the order of the fields in the html template, but the first field in the form always throws this error. When it is not the first field, the 'empNum' control is set up correctly, and the initial value is populated as expected. My hunch is that some strange async behavior is going on, but I am not sure how to fix that if that is the case.

This same code structure is being used for other forms on other collections in the database, and everything works as expected on those forms.

Here is the full code for this component:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { History } from '../history';
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-history-form',
  template: `

    <!-- FORM -->
    <form [formGroup]="historyForm" class="history-form" autocomplete="off" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">

        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
          <input class="form-control" type="number" id="empNum" formControlName="empNum" placeholder="Employee Number">
          <label for="empNum">Employee Number</label>
        </div>

        <div *ngIf="empNum.invalid && (empNum.dirty || empNum.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
          <div *ngIf="empNum.errors?.['required']">
            Employee number is required.
          </div>
        </div>


      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="jobNum" formControlName="jobNum" placeholder="Job Number" required>
        <label for="jobNum">Job Number</label>
      </div>

      <div *ngIf="jobNum.invalid && (jobNum.dirty || jobNum.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
        <div *ngIf="jobNum.errors?.['required']">
          Job number is required.
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="partNum" formControlName="partNum" placeholder="Part Number" required>
        <label for="partNum">Part Number</label>
      </div>

      <div *ngIf="partNum.invalid && (partNum.dirty || partNum.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
        <div *ngIf="partNum.errors?.['required']">
          Part number is required.
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="machArea" formControlName="machArea" placeholder="Machine / Area" required>
        <label for="machArea">Machine / Area</label>
      </div>

      <div *ngIf="machArea.invalid && (machArea.dirty || machArea.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
        <div *ngIf="machArea.errors?.['required']">
          Machine / Area is required.
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="action" formControlName="action" placeholder="Action" required>
        <label for="action">Action</label>
      </div>

      <div *ngIf="action.invalid && (action.dirty || action.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
        <div *ngIf="action.errors?.['required']">
          Action is required.
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <input class="form-control" type="number" id="tTime" formControlName="tTime" placeholder="Total Time" required>
        <label for="tTime">Total Time</label>
      </div>

      <div *ngIf="tTime.invalid && (tTime.dirty || tTime.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
        <div *ngIf="tTime.errors?.['required']">
          Total Time is required.
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <input class="form-control" type="number" id="qtyReq" formControlName="qtyReq" placeholder="Quantity Required" required>
        <label for="qtyReq">Quantity Required</label>
      </div>

      <div *ngIf="qtyReq.invalid && (qtyReq.dirty || qtyReq.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
        <div *ngIf="qtyReq.errors?.['required']">
          Quantity is required.
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <input class="form-control" type="number" id="qtyConf" formControlName="qtyConf" placeholder="Quantity Conforming" required>
        <label for="qtyConf">Quantity Conforming</label>
      </div>

      <div *ngIf="qtyConf.invalid && (qtyConf.dirty || qtyConf.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
        <div *ngIf="qtyConf.errors?.['required']">
          Quantity Conforming is required.
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <input class="form-control" type="number" id="qtyNonConf" formControlName="qtyNonConf" placeholder="Quantity Non-Conforming" required>
        <label for="qtyNonConf">Quantity Non-Conforming</label>
      </div>

      <div *ngIf="qtyNonConf.invalid && (qtyNonConf.dirty || qtyNonConf.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
        <div *ngIf="qtyNonConf.errors?.['required']">
          Quantity Non-conforming is required.
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <input class="form-control" type="number" id="opNum" formControlName="opNum" placeholder="Operation Number" required>
        <label for="opNum">Operation Number</label>
      </div>

      <div *ngIf="opNum.invalid && (opNum.dirty || opNum.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
        <div *ngIf="opNum.errors?.['required']">
          Operation Number is required.
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <input class="form-control" type="number" id="machCost" formControlName="machCost" placeholder="Machine Cost" required>
        <label for="machCost">Machine Cost</label>
      </div>

      <div *ngIf="machCost.invalid && (machCost.dirty || machCost.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
        <div *ngIf="machCost.errors?.['required']">
          Machine Cost is required.
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <input class="form-control" type="number" id="laborCost" formControlName="laborCost" placeholder="Labor Cost" required>
        <label for="laborCost">Labor Cost</label>
      </div>

      <div *ngIf="laborCost.invalid && (laborCost.dirty || laborCost.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
        <div *ngIf="laborCost.errors?.['required']">
          Labor Cost is required.
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <input class="form-control" type="number" id="totalCost" formControlName="totalCost" placeholder="Total Cost" required>
        <label for="totalCost">Total Cost</label>
      </div>

      <div *ngIf="totalCost.invalid && (totalCost.dirty || totalCost.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
        <div *ngIf="totalCost.errors?.['required']">
          Total Cost is required.
        </div>
      </div>


      <!-- DATE TIME PICKER -->
      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <input
          type="datetime-local"
          class="form-control"
          formControlName="dateTime"
          placeholder="Select Date and Time"
          id="dateTime"
          />
        <label for="dateTime">Select Date and Time</label>
      </div>

      <div *ngIf="dateTime.invalid && (totalCost.dirty || totalCost.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
        <div *ngIf="totalCost.errors?.['required']">
          Date is required.
        </div>
      </div>

      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" [disabled]="historyForm.invalid">Submit</button>

</form>


`,
  styles: [
    //  `.history-form {
    //   max-width: 560px;
    //   margin-left: auto;
    //   margin-right: auto;
    //  }`
  ]

})
export class HistoryFormComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  initialState: BehaviorSubject<History> = new BehaviorSubject(<History>{});

  @Output()
  formValuesChanged = new EventEmitter<History>();

  @Output()
  formSubmitted = new EventEmitter<History>();

  historyForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  get empNum() { return this.historyForm.get('empNum')!; }
  get jobNum() { return this.historyForm.get('jobNum')!; }
  get partNum() { return this.historyForm.get('partNum')!; }
  get machArea() { return this.historyForm.get('machArea')!; }
  get action() { return this.historyForm.get('action')!; }
  get tTime() { return this.historyForm.get('tTime')!; }
  get qtyReq() { return this.historyForm.get('qtyReq')!; }
  get qtyConf() { return this.historyForm.get('qtyConf')!; }
  get qtyNonConf() { return this.historyForm.get('qtyNonConf')!; }
  get opNum() { return this.historyForm.get('opNum')!; }
  get machCost() { return this.historyForm.get('machCost')!; }
  get laborCost() { return this.historyForm.get('laborCost')!; }
  get totalCost() { return this.historyForm.get('totalCost')!; }
  get dateTime() { return this.historyForm.get('dateTime')!; } 

  // get dateTime() {
  //   const dateTime = String(this.historyForm.get('dateTime')!);
  //   return (new Date(dateTime).toISOString);
  // }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initialState.subscribe(history => {
      this.historyForm = this.fb.group({
        empNum: [history.empNum, [Validators.required]],
        jobNum: [history.jobNum, [Validators.required]],
        partNum: [history.partNum, [Validators.required]],
        machArea: [history.machArea, [Validators.required]],
        action: [history.action, [Validators.required]],
        tTime: [history.tTime, [Validators.required]],
        qtyReq: [history.qtyReq, [Validators.required]],
        qtyConf: [history.qtyConf, [Validators.required]],
        qtyNonConf: [history.qtyNonConf, [Validators.required]],
        opNum: [history.opNum, [Validators.required]],
        machCost: [history.machCost, [Validators.required]],
        laborCost: [history.laborCost, [Validators.required]],
        totalCost: [history.totalCost, [Validators.required]],
        // to get correct initial dateTime format, must convert to JS Date object, then to ISO String,
        // then slice off the timezone portion. 
        // pushing back to database: + ".000+00:00" to the date string.
        dateTime: [new Date(history.dateTime).toISOString().slice(0, 19), [Validators.required]],
      });

      // Manually trigger change detection
      this.cdr.detectChanges();

      // console.log(this.historyForm.value);
      // console.log(this.empNum.value, this.jobNum.value, this.opNum.value)
      // const empNumState = this.historyForm.get('empNum')
      // console.log(empNumState);

    });

    this.historyForm.valueChanges.subscribe((val) => { this.formValuesChanged.emit(val); });
  }


  submitForm() {
    console.log(this.historyForm.value);
    this.formSubmitted.emit(this.historyForm.value);
  }
}
```

Any possible fixes or tips are greatly appreciated. I am new to Angular, so I am sure that I am probably missing something.

I tried manually triggering change detection in ngOnInit() with no success. I also commented out all of the validation checks in the html, which did not change anything as well.

Comment: You should declare and initialize the FormGroup instance before subscribing to the observable. When the observable is subscribed and returned with value, you set/patch the value to the formGroup. As your current implementation, you only set the FormGroup with FormControl when the observable is returned. That's why the error mentions that the form control can't be found.

Comment: This has fixed the issue. Thank you so much Yong!

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved by initializing empty FormGroup controls in the FormBuilder constructor.

```
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.historyForm = this.fb.group({
      empNum: ["", [Validators.required]],
      jobNum: ["", [Validators.required]],
      partNum: ["", [Validators.required]],
      machArea: ["", [Validators.required]],
      action: ["", [Validators.required]],
      tTime: ["", [Validators.required]],
      qtyReq: ["", [Validators.required]],
      qtyConf: ["", [Validators.required]],
      qtyNonConf: ["", [Validators.required]],
      opNum: ["", [Validators.required]],
      machCost: ["", [Validators.required]],
      laborCost: ["", [Validators.required]],
      totalCost: ["", [Validators.required]],
      dateTime: ["", [Validators.required]],
    });
  }
```

Thank you to Yong Shun for pointing this out!